# Fastest way to draw a wave distortion effect in Delphi FMX?

Tags: performance, delphi, firemonkey, effects

In Delphi 10.2. using Firemonkey for a Windows 10 desktop application I would like distort the image of a `TImage` according to a wave function (or a Perlin Noise function or a similar function).

On the creation of the application's main form I first calculate the wave (or noise) data and keep it in a 3 dimensional array `var WaveData: array[0..MaxNumOfFunctionValues-1, 0..BitmapWidth-1, 0..BitmapHeight-1] of Integer`.

On a `TTimer.OnTimer` event I initiate the drawing of the distortion by calling the following procedure:

```delphi
    procedure DrawWaveDistortion;
    var
      SourceBitmap, TargetBitmap: TBitmap;
      SourceBitmapData, TargetBitmapData: TBitmapData;
      MapAccessOk: Boolean;
      BMWidth, BMHeight: Integer;
      ix, iy: Integer;
      Shift: Integer;
      Shiftedix, Shiftediy: Integer;
      Color: TAlphaColor;
    begin
      SourceBitmap:=Image1.Bitmap;
      BMWidth:=SourceBitmap.Width;
      BMHeight:=SourceBitmap.Height;
      TargetBitmap:=TBitmap.Create(BMWidth, BMHeight);
      try
        MapAccessOk:=SourceBitmap.Map(TMapAccess.Read, SourceBitmapData);
        try
          if MapAccessOk then
          begin
            MapAccessOk:=TargetBitmap.Map(TMapAccess.Write, TargetBitmapData);
            try
              if MapAccessOk then
              begin
                for ix := 0 to BMWidth-1 do
                begin
                  for iy := 0 to BMHeight-1 do
                  begin
                    Shift:=WaveData[StepCounter, ix, iy];
                    Shiftedix:=EnsureRange(ix+Shift, 0, BMWidth-1);
                    Shiftediy:=EnsureRange(iy+Shift, 0, BMHeight-1);
                    Color:=SourceBitmapData.GetPixel(Shiftedix, Shiftediy);
                    TargetBitmapData.SetPixel(ix, iy, Color);
                  end;
                end;
              end;
            finally
              TargetBitmap.Unmap(TargetBitmapData);
            end;
          end;
        finally
          SourceBitmap.Unmap(SourceBitmapData);
        end;
        Image1.Bitmap.Assign(TargetBitmap);
        Inc(StepCounter);
        if StepCounter>=MaxNumOfFunctionValues then
        begin
          StepCounter:=0;
        end;
      finally
        FTargetBitmap.Free;
      end;
    end;
```

I use 32 ms for the `TTimer.Interval`.

This works fine and animates the `TImage` with some sort of water wave effect. However it is to slow, the number of frames per second is low and so I do get a jerky animation (specially when I try to add some other effects).

What can I try to do to improve the performance and increase the number of frames per second?

Comment: If you want to increase performance move from CPU processing to GPU processing. Delphi FMX allows easy way of applying effects to any FMX control by using many build-in effects. Amongst them is also [TWaveEffect](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Filter.Effects.TWaveEffect) that also has property [TWaveEffect.Time](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Filter.Effects.TWaveEffect.Time) which allows you to animate wave movement over time.  For instance increasing the said `Time` property by 0.001 in a 1 MS timer results in a nice smooth wave animation.

Comment: I know TWaveEffect. However the behavior of this effect is not what I need. And as mentioned above I need the possibility to use different functions like Perlin noise functions, overlapping wave functions etc. So I need to be able to freely design the function which is the basis for the distortion.

Comment: There is another way. What you could do is define your image as material that is then using custom shader in order to generate wave effects. So you might want to check [Introduction to Shader Programming](https://blog.grijjy.com/2021/01/14/shader-programming/) article that explains on how to use different shaders in FMX. I remember from a few years ago when I was learning on how Perlin Noise actually work that it can be written into a single shader that is then entirely processed by GPU. To bad I no longer have link to that article since it actually contained example shader for wave effects